# Exchange 07 undeliverable (maximum message size) even though size is smaller then set limit

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange

I have the max send/receive file size set at 75MB each. When i try to send a 10mb PDF from outlook to a gmail account i get the undeliverable message.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you turn off the limit does it send ok?

Answer (score 1):

You may be sending it ok, but gmail could be rejecting it as it is over their max (25MB) (Note it is possible for a 10Mb Pdf could be encoded in such a way that exceeds 25MB)

See https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=8770

Also, there are various different limits in Exchange 2007. You can limits on the individual user's mailboxes and you can also have limits on the send connectors.